# Why was this story id question closed as a duplicate? No evidence of concurrence from the author is present

Tags: discussion

This question was closed as a duplicate by "community bot" without concurrence by the author that it actually is a duplicate. At least, there is no evidence of concurrence.

Is there a reason why? And how does "Community Bot" get to do this against site policy?

[Book where a boy finds out he's the new king of an icy kingdom and can turn into a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270378/28516)

Comment: Typically when the community bot closes a question as a dupe, it's because someone voted to close it as a duplicate and the OP clicked the button to say that they agreed.

Comment: In [review](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/195950) it only got one "Leave Open" vote, so Valorum must have it correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Being closed by the Community bot is, itself, concurrence from the author.**

The only way that the Community bot can close a question as a duplicate is if the author themselves agrees that it is a duplicate. When any question is flagged as a duplicate, there's a special banner, only visible to the OP, which gives them the option to either agree that it's a duplicate (which automatically closes the question) or not. This has been a feature since 2015: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/278659)

Comment: The last comment by the OP starts off "No that's not it", but then 4 minutes later it was closed by the community bot, so it's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @Martha Yeah. I undeleted all the comments there, so that everything is transparent for anyone who may want to reopen-vote. I feel quite unsure but didn't want to modhammer it.